# Dapper, avoiding "The connectionstring property has not been initialized" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I have a problem in my application when I try to call two methods and each one does a query in the database.
These methods are using the using statement, so it closes the connection after the use.

I created a DapperContext, and I'm using simple injector to initialize, via constructor:

```
public DapperContext(int idPortal)
{
    _connectionString = GetERPConnectionString(idPortal);
}
```

To open the connection and do a query in the database, I created a property like this:

```
public IDbConnection DapperConnection
{
    get
    {
        if (_connection == null)
        {
            _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);                    
        }

        if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _connection.Open();
        }

        return _connection;
    }
}
```

This DapperContext has a Dispose method, where it closes the connection:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }

    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

In the Repository class, there's a method that will execute 2 distinct Sqls and these 2 sqls is specified each one in it's method.
Basically, each one initializes like this:

```
using (IDbConnection conexao = dapperContext.DapperConnection)
{
... runs a query
}
```

When I call the first method, the query runs nicely, but when the second mehod is called, in the DapperConnection property, a error happens in _connection.Open(), because the _connectionString is empty.

What is the best approach to avoid this error? I know the connectionString is being lost because of the Dispose method, but as I'm using the SimpleInjector to create my instance and this is done by request, I'll only have this connectionString again in another request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (IDbConnection conexao = dapperContext.DapperConnection)
{
}
// -> conexao.Dispose() called on bound out, and _connection.Close(); is closed.
```

Its result of "_connection" closed connection state without reuse usage. So, if you wanna keep this code works then Dispose method should looks like:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_connection != null && _connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        _connection.Close();
        _connection = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Sergey, I did this in the Dispose method, so at least the _connectionString is not empty anymore, so I was able to create the _connection again with no errors.